# How can I Retrieve the GUID of a CRM 2011 Record in aspx

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011

How can i retrieve the GUID of a Dynamics CRM 2011 Record in aspx?

Comment: Take some time and elaborate your question. You will get better answers, with a clear question

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way is to:
Open the record, press **CTRL+N**,
the same window will open in a new window,

The URL will be something like below:

http: //domain:port/org_name/main.aspx?etc=1&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d1%26etc%3d1%26 **id** %3d%257b **58F90084-FC3C-E111-9A7A-001CC41F0B32** %257d%26rskey%3d63145471&pagetype=entityrecord

as you can see that the GUID starts after %257b which is equivalent to {

and the GUID ends before %257d which is equivalent to }

Comment: To add to this, the guid will have all uppercase letters as the rest of the URL will be lowercase to help pull that info out.